# Minimum clique cover problem: how to generate test cases?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, clique-problem

How can I generate non trivial test cases for a minimum clique cover algorithm?

In other words, I'd like to generate a graph for which the minimum number of cliques and the assignment of each node to a clique are known in advance.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd start with finding the algorithm to check solutions against the output from the algorithm itself. Looking at that would maybe provide insight.

Comment: Depends what you mean by non trivial.  The simplest clique is three vertices joined together in a triangle.  A graph with three cliques that, together, include all vertices is a 9 vertex graph arranged in 3 triangles.  Assume you want something more complex than that.  But what?

Comment: Could you comment on the sizes of graph you're exploring: what range of vertices & edge densities?

Comment: to give an idea: 100 vertices and few thousands of edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a lot of work on clique discovery in Rust.

In general, I've found that a cover of size k is hardest to find when the cliques are approximately equal size, so for my own testing that's what I generated. The approach is basically:

Input:

```
number of vertices (call this n), 
number of cliques in the cover (call this k), 
and the fraction of potential edges that exist (call this p).
```

Procedure:

```
Generate k approximately equal sized cliques (approximate in that some will be larger by 1 vertex if n%k != 0)
Calculate the remaining edges: p*choose(n, 2) - (edges used up by k cliques)
Randomly assign remaining edges to pairs of nonadjacent vertices.
```

Here's the Rust code I used to generate random graphs with a specified number of cliques:

```
fn get_random_graph_with_k_cliques(
  num_vertices: usize,
  cliques_ct: usize,
  edge_probability: f64,
) -> Graph {
  if cliques_ct == 0 {
    return get_random_graph(num_vertices, edge_probability);
  }

  let mut ret_graph = Graph::new(num_vertices);
  let mut edge_candidates_remaining = num_vertices * (num_vertices - 1) / 2;
  let mut edges_remaining = (edge_candidates_remaining as f64 * edge_probability) as usize;

  let reserved_edges = cliques_ct * (num_vertices / cliques_ct) * (num_vertices / cliques_ct - 1)
    / 2
    + (num_vertices % cliques_ct) * (num_vertices / cliques_ct);
  edge_candidates_remaining -= reserved_edges;
  if reserved_edges > edges_remaining {
    edges_remaining = 0;
  } else {
    edges_remaining -= reserved_edges;
  }

  for i in 0..(ret_graph.size - 1) {
    for j in (i + 1)..(ret_graph.size) {
      if i % cliques_ct == j % cliques_ct {
        ret_graph.vertices[i].neighbors_bv.set(j, true);
        ret_graph.vertices[j].neighbors_bv.set(i, true);
      } else if fastrand::f64() < (edges_remaining as f64) / (edge_candidates_remaining as f64) {
        edges_remaining -= 1;
        ret_graph.vertices[i].neighbors_bv.set(j, true);
        ret_graph.vertices[j].neighbors_bv.set(i, true);
      }

      if i % cliques_ct != j % cliques_ct {
        edge_candidates_remaining -= 1;
      }
    }
  }
  for i in 0..(ret_graph.size) {
    if ret_graph.vertices[i].neighbors_bv.any() {
      ret_graph.vertices[i].has_neighbors = true;
    }
  }
  ret_graph.conform_cliques_to_vertices();
  ret_graph
}
```

This is simulating a graph with a known clique cover and a known edge ratio ((count of edges) / (count of potential edges == count of pairs of distinct vertices).

This makes k equal-sized cliques, then adds random edges to get the total edge count desired.

You can ignore the conform_cliques_to_vertices() line. For my purposes, when a vertex was added to a clique I 'merged' it, treating the clique as a vertex with the intersection of edges out of the clique, but your needs may differ.

While this generates a graph with a known clique cover of size k, it doesn't guarantee that a better clique cover doesn't exists, and with randomness, especially given larger edge probabilities, it's certainly possible that a better clique cover exists.

For actually finding cliques, I'd recommend looking into the iterated greedy & Tabu methods. There's a nice paper summarizing several different approaches: A survey of local search methods for graph coloring, by Galinier & Hertz

Comment: I'll add that there seems to be a 'ridge of difficulty' for finding cliques in terms of the number of cliques in the graph and the number of extra edges. For too-few extra edges, it's very easy to find all the cliques. For too-many, there are many solutions and it's easy to find one (also possibly through randomness you find a solution with fewer cliques than the generated cover). Somewhere between those there's a zone where the randomized techniques I tried generally failed to recreate the optimal known cover.

Comment: "This makes k equal-sized cliques, then adds random edges to get the total edge count desired."  This seems as if it would possibly add enough edges between two cliques that they would become one and so give the wrong intersection number.

Comment: @ravenspoint Yep. If the OP cares, that's trivially avoided by insisting on one random non-edge between every pair of cliques. What's harder to avoid in graphs which are still dense after the cliques are taken care of (dense in inter-clique edges), is the creation of sufficient wholly new cliques that an alternate, smaller cover exists.

Comment: "one random non-edge "  What is a non-edge?

Comment: A pair of vertices that are disallowed to be an edge. @ravenspoint

Comment: Hi all, I confirm that adding random edges, even having one random non-edge between each pair of cliques, can lead to the possibility of having a smaller cover.

Comment: @MarcoM This sufficed for my needs. Can I ask, whick clique detection approach are you using?

Comment: Hi @Dave, most probably this could be enough for us, too.
We're using linear programming, finding (brute forcing) all possible cliques and letting the optimizer cover the full graph with the minimum clique count.

Comment: " insisting on one random non-edge between every pair of cliques."  Simpler: insisting on one random vertex in each clique that cannot be used for the added edges.

Comment: "If the OP cares," Why would the OP not care?  The main point seems to be to generate a graph with a known intersection number.

Comment: @ravenspoint That's up to the OP. If they want to test clique detection software, a graph with a known k-clique cover (but the possibility of better existing) and no ancillary structure may be better than one with a known minimum clique cover but added structure that diverges from the sort of graph the software will be used on after testing.

Comment: @ravenspoint For example, clique detection will be trivial in your solution because almost every neighbor of almost every vertex is in the same clique. Iterated greedy will detect these in very few iterations. I.e., while your approach perfectly generates graphs with a known minimum clique cover, I don't believe it will be useful for testing the OPs clique detection algorithm.

Comment: Good point.  I will add extra edges between clique members, stopping short of reducing the intersection number

Comment: @ravenspoint If you're interested, I have a case where iterated greedy fails (the ridge of difficulty): 204 vertices, 12 equal-sized cliques, and 15,530 total edges (75% of choose(204,2)). When placing those added edges at random, IG fails to find a solution even after billions of iterations. For 9 cliques (other params the same) it takes about 1500 iterations, for 10 it takes 200-500k, for 11 it takes about 1-10 million, and 12 (and 13 and 14) never complete, then for 15+ there are many solutions. I think comparing average iterations to solve random graphs might help determine whether the ...

Comment: @ravenspoint ... structure you've introduced has made the graph 'easy' to solve. Since I already have the IG code written, I might test this if I can find time.

Comment: @ravenspoint That was the second half of a comment that spilled over -- the point is that adding structure might or might not made a graph easy to solve, so I'm suggesting a test. I don't know enough to claim that it definitely does.

Comment: For our case even having a test case with an upper bound for the # of cliques can be useful. 
We're checking how much sparse are our real world graphs to be sure of this, i.e. we need to check how much representative of our problems are the syntetic test cases built with your suggestions Dave and ravenspoint. btw thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

**Algorithm**

- Input **I** the *intersection number*.  ( i.e. the minimum number of cliques that, together, cover every vertex in the graph. )
- Input ni numbers, the number of vertices in each of the **I** cliques.  Each number must be 3 or more.
- Construct **I** vertices { VI }, linked together in a circle so that each vertex is connected to two others
- LOOP i over **I**

  - Construct ni - 1 vertices { ni }
  - Connect every vertex in { ni } to every other one in { ni } and to the ith member of { VI }
- RANDOMIZE the order of vertices and links ( to obscure the construction )

**C++ implementation**

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include "../PathFinder/src/cGraph.h"   // https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder

int intersectionNumber;
std::vector<int> vCliqueCount;
raven::graph::cGraph g;

void input()
{
    std::cout << "Intersection Number: ";
    std::cin >> intersectionNumber;
    std::cout << "clique counts:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < intersectionNumber; i++)
    {
        int cc;
        std::cout << "#" << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> cc;
        vCliqueCount.push_back(cc);
    }
}

void generate()
{
    std::string previs;
    std::vector<std::string> vsclique;
    for (int i = 0; i < intersectionNumber; i++)
    {
        auto is = std::to_string(i);
        auto is0 = is+"_0";
        if (i > 0)
            g.add(is0, previs);
        previs = is0;

        vsclique.clear();
        for( int c1 = 0; c1 < vCliqueCount[i]-1; c1++ ) {
            vsclique.push_back(is+"_"+std::to_string(c1+1));
            g.add( is0,vsclique.back());
        }
        for( int c1 = 0; c1 < vsclique.size(); c1++ )
        {

            for( int c2 = c1+1; c2 < vsclique.size(); c2++ )
                g.add(vsclique[c1],vsclique[c2]);
        }
    }
    if( intersectionNumber>2)
        g.add("0_0", previs);

}

void output()
{
    std::ofstream ifs("gengraph.txt");
    if( ! ifs.is_open())
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open output");

    auto vl = g.edgeList();

    // this outputs vertex names that reveal the clique each vertex belongs to
    // for( auto& l : vl )
    // {
    //     ifs << "l " << g.userName(l.first)
    //          <<" "<<g.userName(l.second)<< "\n";
    // }

    // this outputs obscured graph construction
    std::random_shuffle( vl.begin(),vl.end());
    std::map<int,int>  obvertex;
    int kv = 0;
    for( auto& l : vl )
    {
        obvertex.insert(std::make_pair(l.first,kv++));
        obvertex.insert(std::make_pair(l.second,kv++));
        ifs << std::to_string(obvertex.find(l.first)->second)
             <<" "<<std::to_string(obvertex.find(l.second)->second)<< "\n";
    }

}

main()
{
    input();
    generate();
    output();

    return 0;
}
```

**Test Run**

Input

```
Intersection Number: 3
clique counts:
#1: 3
#2: 4
#3: 5
```

Output ( obscured )

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
2 7
2 9
5 11
7 11
14 15
9 3
0 15
1 15
7 4
0 14
0 27
4 11
1 27
7 5
2 0
27 15
1 14
7 0
27 14
```

Output ( vizgraph layout )

[image]

Windows build: https://github.com/JamesBremner/genclique/releases/tag/v1.0.0

**Extra Edges**

To further obscure the clique construction, we can add edges between vertices in different cliques stopping short of reducing the intersection number below specified.  ( Suggestion by @Dave )

Each vertex in a clique has an index number.  The vertex labels look like this "X_Y" where X is the clique index and Y is the vertex index in the clique, all indices zero-based.  The zeroth vertex is the one connected to the other zeroth vertices in two other cliques during the initial construction.  We now add edges between the other vertices, except for the vertices indexed 0 ( already connected to other cliques ) and 1 ( to prevent collapsing the intersection number ) to the vertices in other cliques, except for the same two exceptions.

It is probably easier to see what is going on if you look at the unobscured graphs that the code in the github repo outputs.

Here is the code

```
void extraEdges()
{
    // loop over all cliques
    for (int c1 = 0; c1 < intersectionNumber; c1++)
    {
        auto is = std::to_string(c1) + "_1";

        // loop over other cliques, not already connected to c1
        for (
            int c2 = c1 + 1;
            c2 < intersectionNumber;
            c2++)
        {
            // loop over vertices on other clique, except numbers 0 and 1
            for (int v = 2; v < vCliqueCount[c2]; v++)
            {
                auto sv2 = std::to_string(c2) + "_" + std::to_string(v);
                g.add(is, sv2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout of the simplest construction, unobscured

2
3
3
[image]

Here is the layout ( obscured ) of a larger construction

3
3
4
5

[image]

Complete code, including extra edges and vizgraph layout at https://github.com/JamesBremner/genclique

Comment: Could you please add an plain English description of the extraEdges() code? I.e., for which vertex pairs this adds an extra edge?

Comment: @Dave Done!......

Comment: I'll restate this to confirm I understand. We label the cliques 0, 1, ... and the vertices of clique i as i_0, i_1, .... We join all pairs of edges within each clique. Then, we make a circle out of the 0'th vertex of each clique. Finally, for every pair of cliques i < j, we add edges from i_1 to all vertices of clique k with an id >= 2. But if that's right, I think 10 must be the 0th vertex of the triangle in your 2nd example, and 1 must have ID 1, but if that's the case, why isn't 1 connected to 2 vertices of K4 and 4 of K5? I must be missing something.

Comment: "I think 10 must be the 0th vertex"  The vertices and links are obscured ( using std::random_shuffle() ).  There is no obvious relationship between the numbering of the obscured outputs and the labels used in constructing the graphs.

Comment: Sure, but {1,9,10} is the K3, {0,2,7,11} is the K4 and {3,4,5,6,8} the K5. The only candidate for the circle is {2,3,10}, which uses the 10 from K3. Let's call the K3 clique 0, the K4 clique 1, and the K5 clique 2. Since 10 is on the circle, it must be 0_0, and since 9 isn't connected to anything outside of K3, it must be 0_1, leaving the 1 to be 0_2. But it's only connected to 1 vertex in the K4 and 1 in the K5. Ignoring all that, outside of the clique edges and the circle edges, there are only 4 extra edges: (0,6), (0,8), (1,6), (1,11).

Comment: This might be the source: Line 71 "for (int v = 2; v < vCliqueCount[c1]; v++)". Here you're picking the vertices of clique 2 to connect vertex 1 of clique 1 to, but you're using vCliqueCount[c1]. I think you might have wanted to use vCliqueCount[c2].

Comment: Fixed https://github.com/JamesBremner/genclique/issues/1

Comment: I ran iterated greedy with simulated annealing starting at the millionth iteration and gradually slowing down for the graph this generates for 205 vertices, 12 nearly-identical sized cliques (one has 1 more vertex than the rest). Here are the iterations: (5,204,055), (7), (49,994,196), (21,412,282), (107,680,229), (22), (1,000,016), (25), (9,754,647). As you can see it varies a lot, primarily because my annealing is so slow.

Comment: Running iterated greedy (IG) with annealing starting after just 10k iterations, we get: (21,819),  (8), (8), (6), (957,843), (12), (477,095). You might wonder why, when single-digit solutions are so common, a bad start even with fast annealing can take nearly a million iterations on an identical graph. The answer is the flavor of annealing, which doesn't start from a random ordering of all vertices, but rather plucks one vertex from a clique, connects it to a neighbor not in the same clique, puts this new tiny clique at the start of the IG queue, and continues from there.

Comment: For this specific graph, an annealing step that starts from scratch each time would almost certainly be a lot faster, but I don't believe this is generally true.

Comment: Annealing matters a lot for IG because a bad start can lead to situation where, without annealing, the optimal solution can never be reached.

Comment: +1 for coming up with a non-trivial graph guaranteed to have exactly the desired minimum clique cover, though IMO a random graph with a guaranteed upper limit on the minimum clique cover is better suited to testing clique cover algorithms. In general, the difficulty scales with the ratio of 'bad edges' to 'good edges' where the former are edges non in a clique of the minimum clique cover, and the latter are in such a clique. The worse this ratio is, the likelier it is that IG gets stuck. Of course, the OP may be using an entirely different or novel method with different characteristics.